# Java date compareTo failed

Tags: java, date, compareto

Even if the date is equal or not equal CompareTo failes. It just print 1.

CompareTo doesn't return 0 on comparison. !!

this silly code squeeze my head. Hey friends where i made foul?

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class date {

public static void main (String args[]) throws ParseException
{


    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date expiry = sdf.parse("2012-11-09");


    System.out.println(sdf.format(expiry));


    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime(expiry);
    cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, -2);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(cal1.getTime()));
    System.out.println(sdf.format(cal2.getTime()));
    int j = cal1.compareTo(cal2);

    System.out.println("The result is :" + j);
}

}
```

Comment: You never set `cal2`. Your code prints this: `2012-11-09
2012-11-07
2012-11-07
The result is :-1`

Comment: Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance(); is this enough to get today

Comment: @Tichodroma i get sop of cal1 and cal2

Comment: I suggest you try Joda Time as it has classes like LocalDate for dealing with the date without worrying about the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`compareTo` tells the truth. You've just hidden the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds from the output.

The `expiry` date is set to a day at `00:00:00.0000` (the very first millisecond of that day) while `cal2` still carries the actual time.

Comment: I agree. Try to avoid the dateformatter in your println call and you'll see what Adreas says.

Comment: i don't need Millie second. didn't my simpleDateFormat worked ?

Comment: Sure, it works for `cal1` but you don't use it for `cal2`. So you compare a *day* to a *timestamp* and the timestamp's value will (almost) always be higher (if the days are equal)

Answer (score 1):

`compareTo` is the function gives you the solution...
You can just look at here.

http://www.java-examples.com/compare-two-java-date-objects-using-compareto-method-example

Answer (score 1):

CompareTo compares the time values (millisecond offsets from the Epoch) represented by two Calendar objects. If you print both cal1 and cal2 with formating you will see the time difference.

```
System.out.println(cal1.getTime());
System.out.println(cal2.getTime());
```

This will show you exact time holding by two calender instance.